# Add new column with number of occurences (.isin) in other column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, isin

How can I count how often each value in the column `substring` occurs in the column `string` and append the result as a new column given this example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'substring':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a']
'string':['a a b', '', 'a a', 'b', 'a b', 'a c a', '', 'b c a', 'd d']})

  substring string
0         a  a a b
1         b      
2         c    a a
3         a      b
4         b    a b
5         c  a c a
6         d       
7         d  b c a
8         a    d d
```

and here what I'd like the output to look like:

```
  substring string count
0         a  a a b    5
1         b           4
2         c    a a    2
3         a      b    5
4         b    a b    4
5         c  a c a    2
6         d           1
7         d  b c a    1
8         a    d d    5
```

Comment: Why should the count of 'a' be 5? Doesn't 'a' appear 8 times in the 'string' column? Maybe I just don't understand correctly what you want to do.

Comment: Attemptless "question" *and* uncomprehendingly mysterious output? Come on.

Comment: The number of times where ```df['string'].str.contains('a')``` evaluates as ```True```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really explicit, but I **guess** you want to count the number of times the characters (or words?) appear in the string overall, without counting duplicates per string.

You could use a conversion to set and `collections.Counter`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

# count unique elements (here words)
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(x.split()) for x in df['string']))

## alternative for characters
# c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(x) for x in df['string']))

# map counts
df['count'] = df['substring'].map(c)
```

output:

```
  substring string  count
0         a  a a b      5
1         b             4
2         c    a a      2
3         a      b      5
4         b    a b      4
5         c  a c a      2
6         d             1
7         d  b c a      1
8         a    d d      5
```

###### pure pandas variant for the counter (quite slower)

```
c = df['string'].str.split().apply(set).explode().value_counts()
```